# Melting icicles

Tags: thermodynamics, ice

If I break off the bottom half of an icicle, will the top half melt faster?

Comment: Yes, the bottom surface of the top-half icicle will be exposed to the (supposed) warm air instead of being supposed to the low temperature of the lower-half icicle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is of a too low level, not fit for this site standard

Comment: @Sofia That is technically not a valid reason to close a question.

Comment: @Sofia: To second JamalS's comment, the site is intended for [*all* levels of physics questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (link to the help page).

Comment: It would be nice if you told us *why* you think the top half should (or should not) melt faster. As it stands, it is totally unclear why one should ask oneself this question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind:  The question was motivated by my having just spent a few hours hacking off the bottoms of giant icicles hoping that the top ones would now melt faster.  The obvious effect is (per Sofia's observation) that the top half now has (slightly) more surface area exposed to the air.  Perhaps that's the whole story.  But as someone who has never had much occasion to think about such questions, I wondered if there might be other important effects I was overlooking.  That's been known to happen.

Comment: I see. Well, *if* you observed them indeed melting faster, I think that should go into the question. If you're not sure, the question is fine.

Comment: @ACuriousMind:  I spent a few hours hacking off the bottoms, then immediately wondered if I'd been overlooking anything important about the effectiveness of this strategy and posted the question.  Therefore a) there was no time for observation and b) even if there had been, there was no control group, so the observation wouldn't have told me anything anyway.

Comment: PS:  I am quite sympathetic to the possibility that this question is too low-level for this site, and will fully understand if it gets closed.

Comment: @WillO, you've got a pretty solid question here. This has the potential to involve a fair bit of convective heat transfer, phase change and thin film fluid dynamics.  I've only got an introductory text on heat/mass transfer at home.  When I get to work tomorrow I'll take a look at some books on convection, boundary layers and phase change to try to get a better grip on this. Far from the question being too easy, I'm not 100% sure that I'll come up with a firm answer from pure theory.